# How to redirect old php routes in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, routes

I have old urls like http://example.com/products.php?s_productid=231 and now in my proyect whit url would be http://example.com/products/ver/231

How can I make a rule in routes.php to redirect?
Thanks

Comment: You have old URLs where? It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: Yes, my old web page have more than 300 url like http://example.com/products.php?s_productid=231 and my new web have http://example.com/products/ver/231 So I get in google search error 404 when clic on old urls.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do any change in `routes.php`, all you need is to create a Controller "Product", with one Method "ver", which receives 231 (it's id I guess) as a parameter, like this:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function ver($id) {
        // do your things
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: In my project I have a controller Product with ver($id) function but if I clic in http://example.com/products.php?s_productid=231 don't show my correct product 231

Comment: Try something like? example.com/product/ver/231

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the routes in config/routes.php

```
$route['product/ver/(:num)'] = 'product/ver/$1';
```

> `http://example.com/index.php/products/ver/231`

Then the controller

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function ver($id) {
    /*
       echo $id;
    */
}
```

Comment: I try it, but as I have also public function index() to sho all products: example.com/products I allways get a list of all product. Not the page of the product 231 or similar